# Don't understand why I am getting errors: custom attribute panicked - and - unexpected closing delimiter: `)`

Tags: anchor, anchor-test

I am trying create a simple Solana/Rust app using Anchor that publishes a single set of setters and getters like so:

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

#[program]
mod my_program {
    use super::*;

    #[state]
    pub struct MyState {
        pub my_value: u64,
    }

    impl MyState {
        pub fn set_value(&mut self, ctx: Context<SetMyValue>, new_value: u64) -> ProgramResult {
            self.my_value = new_value;
            Ok(())
        }

        pub fn get_value(&self, _ctx: Context<GetMyValue>) -> ProgramResult {
            msg!("The value is: {}", self.my_value);
            Ok(())
        }
    }

    #[derive(Accounts)]
    pub struct SetMyValue<'info> {
        #[account(mut)]
        pub my_state: &'info mut MyState,
    }

    #[derive(Accounts)]
    pub struct GetMyValue<'info> {
        #[account(signer)]
        pub my_account: AccountInfo<'info>,
        pub my_state: AccountInfo<'info>,
    }

    #[access_control(HasOneSig)]
    pub fn set_my_value(ctx: Context<SetMyValue>, new_value: u64) -> ProgramResult {
        ctx.accounts.my_state.set_value(ctx, new_value)
    }

    #[access_control(HasOneSig)]
    pub fn get_my_value(ctx: Context<GetMyValue>) -> ProgramResult {
        ctx.accounts.my_state.get_value(ctx)
    }
}
```

When I build the code I get the following errors of which the symbols `42` and `37` are line numbers:

```
error: custom attribute panicked
  --> /src/lib.rs:42:5
   |
42 |     #[access_control(HasOneSig)]
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 
error: unexpected closing delimiter: `)`
  --> /src/lib.rs:37:5
   |
37 |     #[access_control(HasOneSig)]
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ unexpected closing delimiter
   |
```

Any idea what I need to do to make the fix? It seems to me that the syntax is correct.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide. I will be sincerely grateful.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included your anchor version and the definition of `HasOneSig`

Comment: THANKS! @Ademola I am a newbie. I am working in Solana Playground. 

This seems to be the version of Anchor: 
$ anchor -V
`sugar-cli 0.27.0`

I wonder how do I find definition of `HasOneSig`. Might you be able to tell me?

Comment: @Ademola : I did do a search for `HasOneSig` here https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/ .... but that proved fruitless.

Comment: I'll give an answer below

Answer (score 3):

Does this code originate from somewhere else? There's a few things wrong with it.

Firstly the `#[access_control]` macro usually wraps a function i.e:

`fn check() { ...... }`

and then :

`#[access_control(check())]`.

I've never heard of a `HasOneSig`. Is there a reason for the insistence on putting it in your code? If you need something with that functionality then you're supposed to write it yourself.

Unless its definition exists in some other place but you forgot to port that part over, HasOneSig simply doesn't exist and won't work. This specific panic message though is likely due to the fact that the macro expects a function call with its own parantheses pair.

Separately, `MyState` is annotated with `#[state]` and not `#[account]` hence it can neither be used as an account in your structs nor accessed from ctx.accounts.

Here's some starter guides to get you writing correct anchor code:

- [Basic intro article](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-create-smart-contracts-in-solana-and-anchor-e67ff0747c63).
- [Article series](https://lorisleiva.com/create-a-solana-dapp-from-scratch/getting-started-with-solana-and-anchor).
- [Article](https://learn.figment.io/tutorials/build-a-blog-dapp-using-anchor).
- [The Anchor book/reference](https://book.anchor-lang.com/introduction/introduction.html).

Comment: Thank you! You've inspired me to do the necessary research. The thing I have learned so far is that if a developer is serious about mastering Anchor, it's not matter of copy and paste. I am humbled, appropriately so.